# Difference between following declarations in ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

What is the difference between the following declarations:

```
 ArrayList<Object>  arr=new ArrayList<Object>();

 ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();
```

What happens if we use `add` method or any other method of `ArrayList` in the condition above? How does it work?

Comment: [Best answer ever](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: Please look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ . Its called generics where you specify at compile time on what kind of objects can go through. -1 because homework not done.

Comment: @MarounMaroun it is not generics. Just a row

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera This is the whole lesson, OP will need it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun ahh ok. your poit taken

Comment: To add to what others said, the complier (atleast in eclipse) screams - **You are using a raw type** for `ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Object>  arr=new ArrayList<Object>(); // Object type 

ArrayList arr=new ArrayList(); // raw type
```

What is [row types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

The first one uses [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) to tell the compiler which type of objects the list will hold.
The second one just don´t specify this, therefore any type is possible, but in a modern IDE the IDE will mark this usage as not the best way to do so. 
The advantage of the first one is that the IDE/compiler can tell you when you try to input a wrong type into the list.